# How to create multi agent transactions in Aptos blockchain?

Tags: typescript, blockchain, move, aptos, move-lang

I've written multi-agent-transaction implementation using Aptos Typescript SDK.

**Steps**

Create a new TransactionBuilderRemoteABI instance using the aptosClient and sender address

```
  const builder = new TransactionBuilderRemoteABI(aptosClient, {
    sender: sender.address(),
  });
```

Build the raw transaction with the specified parameters (e.g., function, type_args, args)

```
  const rawTxn = await builder.build(
    "0x15c92120b0aaeb45ee1b7f7d5b0719a3ca1471ef841ccf99561523ff86039219::TwoByTwo::exchange",
    [],
    [10000, 20000]
  );
```

Create a new MultiAgentRawTransaction instance using the raw transaction and receiver address

```
  const multiAgentTxn = new TxnBuilderTypes.MultiAgentRawTransaction(rawTxn, [
    TxnBuilderTypes.AccountAddress.fromHex(receiver.address()),
  ]);
```

Sign the transaction with the sender and receiver signatures

```
  const senderSignature = new TxnBuilderTypes.Ed25519Signature(
    sender
      .signBuffer(TransactionBuilder.getSigningMessage(multiAgentTxn))
      .toUint8Array()
  );
  const receiverSignature = new TxnBuilderTypes.Ed25519Signature(
    receiver
      .signBuffer(TransactionBuilder.getSigningMessage(multiAgentTxn))
      .toUint8Array()
  );
```

Create new AccountAuthenticatorEd25519 instances for the sender and receiver

```
  const senderAuthenticator = new TxnBuilderTypes.AccountAuthenticatorEd25519(
    new TxnBuilderTypes.Ed25519PublicKey(sender.signingKey.publicKey),
    senderSignature
  );
  const receiverAuthenticator = new TxnBuilderTypes.AccountAuthenticatorEd25519(
    new TxnBuilderTypes.Ed25519PublicKey(receiver.signingKey.publicKey),
    receiverSignature
  );
```

Create a new multi-agent authenticator with the sender and receiver authenticators

```
    new TxnBuilderTypes.TransactionAuthenticatorMultiAgent(
      senderAuthenticator,
      [TxnBuilderTypes.AccountAddress.fromHex(receiver.address())], // Secondary signer addresses
      [receiverAuthenticator] // Secondary signer authenticators
    );
```

Convert the signed transaction to bytes using the BCS library

```
  const bcsTxn = BCS.bcsToBytes(
    new TxnBuilderTypes.SignedTransaction(rawTxn, multiAgentAuthenticator)
  );
```

Submit the signed BCS transaction to the Aptos client and log the transaction hash

```
 const transactionRes = await aptosClient.submitSignedBCSTransaction(bcsTxn);
 console.log(transactionRes.hash);
```

The complete code is **[here](https://gist.github.com/0xAnto/498968bed8c7fa527dbabfba39f9285f)**. If you have any issues let me know in the comments.

Comment: This is great content, but not a question. If you could first express what problem you're trying to solve as a question and then include this as an answer that would be great. Otherwise we'll likely have to close this as per Stack Overflow rules.